# MS Word Automation in C# - Unable to cast object of type 'System.String[*]' to type 'System.String[]'

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I use this code to get a String array of headings used in a MS Word 2007 document (.docx):

```
dynamic arr = Document.GetCrossReferenceItems(WdReferenceType.wdRefTypeHeading);
```

Using the debugger, I see that `arr` is dynamically assigned a String array with titles of all my headings in the document (about 40 entries). So far so good.

Then, I want to access the strings, but no matter how I do it, I get the following exception:

```
InvalidCastException: 
           Unable to cast object of type 'System.String[*]' to type 'System.String[]'.
```

I have tried different ways of accessing the strings:

By index:

```
String arr_elem = arr[1];
```

By casting to an IEnumerable:

```
IEnumerable list = (IEnumerable)arr;
```

By using a simple foreach loop:

```
foreach (String str in arr)
{
   Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

However, no matter what I try, I always end up with the same exception as shown above.

Can anyone explain what I am missing here / what I am doing wrong? And especially `String[*]` - what does it mean?

Comment: I have raised this with MS as a bug: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/684538/dynamic-incorrectly-treats-1d-arrays-as-vectors

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try

```
object arr_r = Document.GetCrossReferenceItems(WdReferenceType.wdRefTypeHeading);
Array arr = ((Array) (arr_r));

string myHeading = (string) arr.GetValue(1);
```

Answer (score 8):

`string[]` is a vector - a 1-d, 0-based array. `string[*]`, however, is a regular array that *just happens to have one dimension*. Basically, you are going to have to handle it as `Array`, and either copy the data out, or use the `Array` API rather than the `string[]` API.

This is the same as the difference between `typeof(string).MakeArrayType()` (the vector) and `typeof(string).MakeArrayType(1)` (a 1-d non-vector).

Comment: Do you think it's a bug that the dynamic runtime is trying to access an array as if it were a vector?

Comment: @Gabe - yes: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/684538/dynamic-incorrectly-treats-1d-arrays-as-vectors

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you're using `dynamic` in a situation where it apparently wasn't intended. When the dynamic runtime sees a 1D array, it assumes a vector, and tries to index into it or enumerate it as if it were a vector. This is one of those rare cases where you have a 1D array that is not a vector, so you have to handle it as an `Array`:

```
Array arr = (Array)(object)Document.
            GetCrossReferenceItems(WdReferenceType.wdRefTypeHeading);
// works
String arr_elem = arr.GetValue(1);
// now works
IEnumerable list = (IEnumerable)arr; 
// now works
foreach (String str in arr)
{
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation :) Your first line throws me an InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String[*]' to type 'System.String[]'.

Comment: @sw_lasse: Oops, you're right. I fixed it. My version worked in C# 3.0 but broke in 4.0 due to the apparent bug in the dynamic access of a nonstandard array.