# System.String[*] and System.String[] Difference in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, com

**Edit**: I know that C# equivalent of `For Each server As String In servers` is `foreach(var item in servers)` but since `GetOPCServers` returns object, it should be cast to iterable type.

---

I am developing an application using a COM library. Since 64bit causes problems, my target CPU x86.

All methods works as expected, except `GetOPCServers()`.

Although Visual Basic code using same dll does not cause problem, C# throws `System.InvalidCastException` saying that:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Core.dll
>
> Additional information:
> 'System.String[*]' türündeki nesne 'System.String[]' türüne atılamadı.

Apologizes for the error message, since my OS in Turkish.

> The object in type `System.String[*]` can not be **assigned** to `System.String[]`

What is difference between `System.String[*]` and `System.String[]`?

**The VB code using same dll runs without exception**

```vb
Public Class OpcInfo
  Dim servers As VariantType
  Dim server As OPCAutomation.OPCServer = New OPCAutomation.OPCServer()

  Function GetServers()
    Dim servers As Object
    Dim _servers As New List(Of String)

    servers = server.GetOPCServers()

    For Each server As String In servers
      _servers.Add(server)
    Next
    Return _servers
  End Function
End Class
```

**But the the C# code also uses same dll throws exception**

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var opc_servers = new OPCAutomation.OPCServer().GetOPCServers();
    foreach (var item in (string[])opc_servers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

**More interestingly, I able to view the data in Watch/Immediate windows:**

[image: watch window]

The error code `-2147467262` corresponds to `FFFFFFFF80004002` and the explanation according to https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb632794.aspx

```
E_NOINTERFACE 
FFFFFFFF80004002
-2147467262
No such interface supported
```

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084270/ms-word-automation-in-c-sharp-unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-string)?

Comment: The equivalent c# code to VB code is `foreach (string item in opc_servers)`.

Comment: Thanks. But it also throws exception, since `GetOPCServers` returns `object`

Comment: What about `foreach (var item in opc_servers)`?

Comment: Make the cast inside the loop `(string)item` or `item as string` what better fit.

Comment: It returns a *non-conformant* array, pretty common in COM.  Usually because the lower bound of the array is not 0, 1 is the next common choice.  Cast to (Array) and use Array.GetLower/UpperBound() and Array.GetValue().

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone.

Casting inside the loop does not make the trick.

as @pikoh stated the answer on  [MS Word Automation in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7084442/1766716) made the trick:

And also `var opc_servers = ...` did not work. Must be `object opc_servers = ...`

```
object opc_servers = new OPCAutomation.OPCServer().GetOPCServers();
var servers = ((Array)(opc_servers));


for (int i = 1; i <= servers.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine((string)servers.GetValue(i));
}
```